# Sorting List(Of MaskedTextBox)

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

The list **`Private msklistclass1 As New List(Of MaskedTextBox)`** contains following MaskedTextBox controls after executing the following code

```
 For Each ctrl As Control In Me.pnlclass11.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MaskedTextBox Then
      msklistclass1.Add(ctrl)
    End If
 Next

seat112
seat212
seat312
seat412
seat512
seat612
seat122
seat222
seat322
seat422
seat522
seat622
```

but they aren't in the order I have shown above I suppose. When I try to assign values to these controls in a sequential manner they don't get assigned in an order.

I tried the following code

```
For i = 0 To 11 Step 1
     msklistclass1(i).Text = rno312(i)
Next
```

The assignment I expect is

```
seat112  1138M0321
seat212  1138M0322
seat312  1138M0323
seat412  1138M0324
seat512  1138M0325
seat612  1138M0326
```

But they aren't getting assigned in this order
Is there a possibility to sort the list `msklistclass1`

---

This line gives me the following output  `msklistclass1.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))`

```
seat111  1138M0321  seat121  1138M0321
seat211  1138M0323  seat221  1138M0324
seat311  1138M0325  seat321  1138M0326
seat411  1138M0326  seat421  1138M0327
seat511  1138M0328  seat521  1138M0329
seat611  1138M0330  seat621  1138M0331
```

but I want

```
seat111  1138M0321  seat121  1138M0327
seat211  1138M0322  seat221  1138M0328
seat311  1138M0323  seat321  1138M0329
seat411  1138M0324  seat421  1138M0330
seat511  1138M0325  seat521  1138M0331
seat611  1138M0326  seat621  1138M0332
```

Comment: "they don't get assigned in an order" - Yes they do. They get assigned in the same order as `rno312`.

Comment: `rno312` is list of string and it's sorted before assigning

Comment: If `rno312` is sorted, then so will `msklistclass1` be. What problem are you having?

Comment: I have updated the question with how I assigned the controls to the list. after assigning I executed the second for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ, you can do this:

```
Dim listOrdered = From m In msklistclass1 Order By m.Text
```

Or if you cannot use LINQ or do not want to, then do this:

```
msklistclass1.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Text))
```

Note: If you want to sort by a different property of the `MaskedTextBox`, then just change `Text` to whatever the property name is, like `Name` for instance.

Comment: @varocarbas - I am confused, what code are you talking about?

Comment: nearly there but any other possibility of sort. I can't explain what I am seeing as result

Comment: Sorry my bad. I got the problem: created the maskedTextBox objects without assigning a value to the .Name property. +1 and apologies.

Comment: @varocarbas - no problem, thanks for checking up on it though. :-)

Comment: Oh I realize now what you are saying, I accidentally put `Name` as the property when it should be `Text`, see updated answer.